# Python boolean circuits?

Tags: python, boolean, discrete-mathematics, truthtable

I'm trying to create code that simulates boolean circuits, and is supposed to return true or false (one or zero) based on boolean logic through boolean circuits. I will post the circuit diagrams below. However the output i get is:

```
Ran 9 tests in 0.141s
OK
```

circuit 1:
[image]
circuit 2:
[image]
Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import unittest

# An example: exercise 12.3.1
def circuit_3_1(x, y):
    a1 = x + y
    a2 = not y

    # note: the end result should be returned as 0/1
    #   - bool() transforms any sum larger than 0 into True (False otherwise)
    #   - int() transforms any True into 1 (0 otherwise)
    # int( bool ( n )) will therefore transforms any sum larger than 0 into 1 (0 otherwise)
    return int( bool(a1 and a2))

def circuit_3_2(x, y):
    a1 = not x
    a2 = not y
    a3 = (not a1) and (not a2)


    return int( bool((a3)))
4
def circuit_3_4(x, y, z):
    a1 = (not((not x) and y and z))
    a2=((not x) or y or(not z))
    return int( bool(a1 and a2))


class circuits_unit_tests( unittest.TestCase ):

    def test_circuit_3_1(self):
        self.assertEqual( circuit_3_1(0,0), 0)
        self.assertEqual( circuit_3_1(0,1), 0)
        self.assertEqual( circuit_3_1(1,0), 1)
        self.assertEqual( circuit_3_1(1,1), 0)

    def test_circuit_3_4_000(self):
        self.assertEqual( circuit_3_4(0,0,0), 1)

    def test_circuit_3_4_001(self):
        self.assertEqual( circuit_3_4(0,0,1), 1)

    def test_circuit_3_4_010(self):
        self.assertEqual( circuit_3_4(0,1,0), 1)

    def test_circuit_3_4_011(self):
        self.assertEqual( circuit_3_4(0,1,1), 0)

    def test_circuit_3_4_100(self):
        self.assertEqual( circuit_3_4(1,0,0), 1)

    def test_circuit_3_4_101(self):
        self.assertEqual( circuit_3_4(1,0,1), 0)

    def test_circuit_3_4_110(self):
        self.assertEqual( circuit_3_4(1,1,0), 1)

    def test_circuit_3_4_111(self):
        self.assertEqual( circuit_3_4(1,1,1), 1)

def main():
        unittest.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: If all tests are passing, it means the outputs are as you expect. You have written unit testing code - so all its doing is checking if the output of your methods is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Are you trying to make the tests fail or something? There doesn't seem to be a problem here.

Comment: i've never used unit tester. I think my professor wanted me to write code that passed the test. so i suppose the methods i wrote had correct logic?

Comment: So you've posted some code with unit tests that passed. What is your question?